# Pull data from icinga satellite to master behind firewall

Tags: ssh-tunnel, icinga, private-network

I have the following situation:

A private enterprise network with a Icinga2 master, monitoring the internal servers. The firewall blocks all inbound access, however all servers to have outbound internet access (multiple protocols, such as SSH, HTTP, HTTPS).

We also have an environment in Azure with 1 publicly accessable VM (nginx) and behind that, in a private network, application servers. I'd also like to monitor these servers. I read that I can set up a Icinga2 satellite (in Azure), that monitors the Azure environment and sends the data to the master.

This would be a great solution. However, my master is in our private enterprise network, so the Icinga satellite can't push any data to the master. The only option would be that the master pulls the data periodically from the satellite(s). It's possible for the master to login via SSH agent forwarding to the servers in Azure. Is this possible or is there a better solution? I'd rather not create a reverse SSH tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

You might just use the icinga2 client and let the master connect to the client (ensure that the endpoint object contains host/port attributes). Once the connection is established the client will send its check results (and historical replay logs even if there).